# eclipse for c++ development on sun solaris 10. getting gtk-warning

Tags: c++, eclipse, gtk, solaris

I want to do c++ development on sun solaris 10.0 machine. I downloaded eclipse for solaris 10 but when I run it nothing popsup and I get warnings on command line. How do I bring up eclipse IDE? also will I need any plugin in my eclipse.ini to enable c++ development? there are a whole lot of files under the /plugins directory. I am very new to unix and solaris os.

**Here is my environment**
cat /etc/release
                     Solaris 10 10/09 s10x_u8wos_08a X86
           Copyright 2009 Sun Microsystems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

uname -a
SunOS 5.10 Generic_147441-25 i86pc i386 i86pc

**This is the eclipse I downloaded**
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops4/R-4.6-201606061100/eclipse-SDK-4.6-solaris-gtk-x86_64.zip

**This is the java version**
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)

**This is the warning message**
./eclipse
Eclipse:
GTK+ Version Check
***WARNING: Gtk+ version too old (micro mismatch)
***WARNING: SWT requires GTK 2.18.0
***WARNING: Detected: 2.4.9

(Eclipse:3218): Gdk-WARNING **: gdkdrawable-x11.c:994 drawable is not a pixmap or window

(Eclipse:3218): Gtk-WARNING **: gtkwidget.c:7030: widget class `GtkLabel' has no property named`link-color'

I am using cygwin and running xwindows plugin to support popup windows.

**heres the downloaded eclipse.in**i. I have not made any changes to it.

vi eclipse.ini

```
"eclipse.ini" 13 lines, 320 characters
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.solaris.x86_64_1.1.300.v20160518-1444
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

thanks

Comment: The warning seems pretty clear. Upgrade your version of GTK to at least 2.18.0

Comment: what a pain. I am not a root. downloaded to my home but the dependencies (glib, atk, pange, cairo) are also old. compiling from non-default path also requires a few changes.

Comment: Solaris 10 was released in 2005, and is now in Extended Support, past the end of the primary support life, so all the dependencies are going to be old.   You'll find life much easier on a Solaris 11 based release.